# Module build failed: SyntaxError When i try for asyncComponent in Laravel + React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-laravel

I want to implement asyncComponent in laravel + react. Everything work Good before i tried asyncComponent.

When i try that return error :

Code :

```
import asyncComponent from '../component/asyncComponent';

const Home = asyncComponent(() => import('../pages/home') //line 9
  .then(module => module.default), { name: 'Home' });
```

Error:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   E:/xampp/htdocs/react/lara-react/blog-new/resources/js/back-end/layout/main.js:
>   Unexpected token (9:34)

How to implement asyncComponent in laravel ?

Comment: What's on **line 9** in `E:/xampp/htdocs/react/lara-react/blog-new/resources/js/back-end/layout/main.js`?

Comment: line 9 `const Page1 = asyncComponent(() => import('./components/Page1')` -@Jerodev